# Hopfield Network Energy

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network, networks

Can neurons in Hopfield Network have non-binary values ( continuous values instead of -1 and +1)? If they can have non-binary values , is energy expression for hopfield NN stays the same? What is the main condition for Hopfield energy to stay consistent? I am aksing this particularly because I am wondering if we could consider a text as a Hopfield Network where word occurence frequencies in the text could be neuron states.(For example in this sentence the frequency of the word "sentence" is 2, so the neuron state would be=2). I am wondering if energy of Hopfield NN could work in this case.